# Dependent samples but unable to pair individual scores

Tags: spss, nonparametric

We surveyed a group of students before an in-school year-long project and after, and want to see if the changes in scores are significant. Data doesn't meet assumptions of normality. Can we use the Mann Whitney test (for independent samples) even though these are dependent?

One advice was to do 'bootstrapping' - yet the method I was shown I am not sure will actually help as it pools data from the before-after conditions. Is there a method to do bootstrapping with dependent data in SPSS? For example randomly matching before scores with after scores in all variations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 dependent groups data that do not meet the normality assumption, you can use the Wilcoxon Signed Ranks test. In SPSS go Analyze -> Non-parametric tests -> then select Related Samples or 2-Related Samples in legacy dialogs.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the main problem is we are unable to pair the before and after scores because answers were anonymous. Yet it is the same group...